# Phonegap/Cordova Device API is undefined on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I Have a problem with Cordova/Phonetgap Device API, the objetc device isn't found. I make callback to device.model or any fecture of device and return:

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: device at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:16

I'm following this steps: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device firts create the cordova android project and later I Install plugin device through: "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device" I'm testing with this index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var string = device.platform;
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML =  string;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
     <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have in app/res/xml/config.xml this lines:

```
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

Here There is a screenshot for more details:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6404856/Helpme.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see you're using eclipse, did you run `cordova prepare android` or `cordova build android` after you installed the plugin? (be aware that it will overwrite your assets/www folder with the content of the www folder at the root of the project)

Comment: Yeah!!!! It is now working! Thanks very much!!! I was not doing build android after install of plugin plugin. Nice :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. Try running `cordova plugin ls` and make sure the device plugin shows up. Also try uninstalling then reinstalling it. If that doesn't work then try deleting the `your_project/plugins/android.json` file, reinstall plugin, then build the android platform.  Sometimes the `android.json` doesn't get updated correctly and this messes it all up.